# Bootstrap navbar will disappear when clicking the toggle button on small devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

This is what I have:

```
    <div class="container" style="padding-top: 70px;">
<div id="navbar">
    <!-- Fixed navbar -->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
          <div class="col-xs-2"><img src="img/favicon.png" alt="Dev Icon" height="20px" width="20px"></div><div class="col-xs-10">FrontEnd Dev</div></a>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">

            <?php include('includes/navbar.php'); ?>

        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </nav>
</div>
```

The `<?php include('includes/navbar.php'); ?>` just adds the `<ul class="nav navbar-nav">` with the `<li>` tags from another array file.

This issue only happens when the toggle button is available on smaller devices. Clicking on the button does nothing visually (but it does change classes in the code). Clicking the button a few more times will result in the disappearing of the complete navbar. I removed any other css styling that could affect the navbar but is still the same. I use Bootstrap v3.3.7 using the CDN links from the Bootstrap website.

Comment: can you post the code of `navbar.php` file(entire code please i think the problem lies there)

Comment: This is `navbar.php` : 
```<?php include ('includes/arrays.php'); ?>
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
  <?php 
  foreach ($navItems as $item) {
    echo "<li><a href=\"$item[dir]\">$item[title]</a></li>";
  }
   ?>
</ul>```

Comment: My guess is that you have added the same bootstrap cdn in either `navbar.php` or in `arrays.php`..check it..if that's the case remove it because you should not use cdns more than once in your page..it creates all sorts of problems.

Comment: No. The only CDN is in the header file. Before using CDN I had the bootstrap files downloaded and used them but still the same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem. The toggle button has `data-target="#navbar"` which targets the `<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">`. I didn't realize that I had all the navbar wrapped up in a ´div´ with the id of navbar. So that's where the conflict was.